"A start job is running" but life is short
This is an umbrella question for all "A startup job is running for" issues, regardless of the underlying cause.
For me this usually happens after an improper shutdown or a package installation/uninstallation or with new hardware.
Regardless of what the specific cause is and assuming that a "startup job" is some job configured to run at startup, where can I find this configuration or list of jobs that are scheduled to run at startup (and steal precious time from our short lives)? How do I edit/remove troublesome/unnecessary startup jobs (and live what little is left of my life peacefully)?

If you google for this, you'll find this is usually caused by an improper mounting configuration for one of your file systems. Umbrella questions are not a good fit for these sites.

If you describe the unit that is giving you this problem, and provide the unit file (*.service, *.mount) we can provide advice.

@Stewart where can I find these units on an Ubuntu box?

The "A startup job is running for" message seems typical for systemd. Based on your comments, you seem to be totally unaware of systemd. If you plan to administer Linux distributions that are using systemd, that is not a good state to be in. So, here's a mini-primer on it.
You'll find the part of the configuration installed from packages at /usr/lib/systemd/system/, the local customizations at /etc/systemd/system/ and dynamically generated parts at /run/systemd/system/. Any configuration file in /etc/systemd/system/ will override a file with the same name in the other two locations mentioned.
When the system is running, you can run the command systemctl without any parameters to see a list of systemd units. Any failed units should show up in red if your terminal is capable of colours, or in bold if not.
Note that this list is really a simplified representation: the true form of the list of units is a tree graph of dependencies. See man 7 bootup for a description of the overall boot process, including some ASCII-art graphs of it.
Systemd provides man pages for unit files in general as man systemd.unit and for each unit type as man systemd.service, man systemd.device, man systemd.mount etc.
You might be mostly concerned about *.service units, but note that there are also some *.device and *.mount units which are autogenerated based on udev rules and some classic configuration files such as /etc/fstab and/or /etc/crypttab. The autogeneration is performed by generator scripts located at /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/.
Each system-supplied generator script should have its own man page identifying the configuration file it reads and any kernel command line options you might use to e.g. temporarily override the generator. For a permanent fix in case of autogenerated units, you should go to the configuration file that controls the respective generator and remove or fix any obsolete or erroneus configuration lines that might be causing a delay.
For example, if a *.mount unit is causing a start-up delay because a network share is no longer accessible, just delete the reference to it from /etc/fstab or add a noauto option to it to stop the generator from trying to mount it automatically at boot time.
For *.service units, you'll want to know a few commands:

systemctl status <unit name> will list the current status of the unit and a few last log lines it has generated, if any.
journalctl -u <unit name>.service will show you the full logs produced by the service in question in your favourite pager (defaults to less)
systemctl disable <unit name> will tell systemd "I don't particularly want this service to start at boot, but I'm not opposed to it starting if some other service needs it." If you add the --now option, it will also stop the service right now.
systemctl mask <unit name> will tell systemd "I absolutely don't want this service to start at any time: if some other service would need it, let that other service fail too." If a service is currently running, stop it first before masking it.
systemctl unmask <unit name> will undo a previous systemctl mask operation.
systemctl enable <unit name> will tell systemd "start this service at each future boot until told otherwise". If you add the --now option, it will also start the service immediately.
systemctl start <unit name> and systemctl stop <unit name> will start and stop a service unit immediately, but the new state will not persist over a reboot; you'll need systemctl enable/systemctl disable for that.
if you have modified any unit definitions or any configuration files that are used as information source for generator scripts, you should run systemctl daemon-reload to make those changes effective before doing anything else.

Now you should know just enough about systemd to be dangerous. Please use this as a starting point to learn more.
